# Why do the poles and zeroes of a transfer function cause a slope change in frequency response?

Tags: electrical-engineering, control-engineering

Why is it that as the frequency approaches a pole or zero of a system, the slope of the magnitude of the transfer function changes by 20dB/decade?
Whenever I see this stated when reading about transfer functions, it's never explained. What causes this property of transfer functions?

Answer (score 3):

Have you read about roll-off? Wikipedia has a great explanation of this topic. Basically when you have a pole or zero of a system, you are representing, in this case, the transfer function of a circuit:

[image: Ec1]

[image: Ec2]

To express the magnitude in decibels of the system on a frequency point you use this equation:

[image: Ec3]

Or expressed as a loss:

[image: Ec4]

At frequencies well above ω=1, this simplifies to:

[image: Ec5]

Now, if you want to know the difference in decibels between to frequencies, you may have to use the same equation but this time using (ω2/ω1) in the logarithm.

[image: Ec6]

If the difference here is a decade, or a frequency ten times ω1, the logarithm will be always equal to 1. Then you multiply this result with 20 because of the fifth equation, then you have:

[image: Ec7]

That's it! Maybe you really want to know another reason besides the one I gave to you, but it is explained mathematically.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a result of the definition of poles and zeros of a transfer function.  A transfer function in the Laplace domain [is written as](http://web.mit.edu/2.14/www/Handouts/PoleZero.pdf)
$$
H(s)=\frac{b_ms^m+...+b_2s^2+b_1s+b_0}{a_ns^n+...+a_2s^2+a_1s+a_0}
$$
By factoring the polynomials (which is often not easily achieved by hand) you can rewrite this as
$$
H(s)=\frac{(s-z_1)(s-z_2)...(s-z_m)}{(s-p_1)(s-p_2)...(s-p_n)}.
$$
This form is what defines the poles and zeros; the $p_i$ are the poles and the $z_i$ are the zeros.

To see how this leads to the 20 dB per decade rule, lets consider a concrete example:
$$
H(s)=\frac{(s-1000)}{(s-10)(s-100000)}.
$$
I've intentionally spread the poles and zeros very far out to illustrate the point.  When $s\ll 10$ (i.e. $s$ is much smaller than all of the poles and zeros), then this reduces approximately to $H(s)\approx\frac{1000}{10*100000}$ and the transfer function is flat.  When $s\sim100$ (i.e. much larger than the first pole but smaller than the zero) this becomes approximately $H(s)\approx\frac{1000}{s*100000}$ and the transfer function is falling at 20 dB per decade.  Upon crossing the zero, at say $s\sim10000$, the transfer function becomes approximately $H(s)\approx\frac{s}{s*100000}=\frac{1}{100000}$ and the transfer function is again flat.  Finally for $s\gg100000$ the transfer function becomes approximately $H(s)\approx\frac{s}{s*s}=\frac{1}{s}$, and it is falling at 20 dB per decade again.

Honestly, the best way to get a feel for this rule is to simply plot a number of transfer functions.  There is an online tool [here](http://www.onmyphd.com/?p=bode.plot.online.generator) which allows you to type in an arbitrary number of poles and zeros to see how the Bode plot looks.  The plot below shows its output for the example I described above except that it sets the DC gain to 0 dB.  The 'asymptotic plot' is the approximation that I've described above, and the 'real plot' is the actual Bode plot of the transfer function.

[image: magnitude]

[image: phase]